# Space curve not contained in a plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth complete intersection of two smooth hypersurfaces of degree atleast $4$ in $\mathbb P^3$. Does it necessarily mean that it can not be a smooth plane curve?

If not in general, then can we do the following : Let $X$ be a general surface of degree $d_1 \geq 4$ in $\mathbb P^3$. Let $H$ be the hyperplane divisor. Then can we always choose $C \in |d_2H|$ ($d_2 \geq 4$) such that $C$ becomes a smooth complete intersection of surfaces of degree $d_1,d_2$ in $\mathbb P^3$ but $C$ is not contained in any hyperpalne?

Does some argument along the lines of Bertinis theorem help?

Comment: It is not clear from the way you formulated the question whether the curve is of degree at least 4 or the surfaces are of degree at least 4. In the former case, why can you not have $C=P\cap Q$ where $P$ is a plane and $Q$ a surface of degre at least 4?

Comment: @Kapil, I meant both the surfaces are of degree at least $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Koszul resolution
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}(-d_1-d_2) \to \mathcal{O}(-d_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-d_2) \to I_C \to 0
$$
it is easy to check that $H^0(\mathbb{P}^3, I_C(1)) = 0$, hence $C$ is not contained in a hyperplane.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Could you please give a reference how this short exact sequence is constructed? In this context are we using the fact that $C$ is a  strict complete intersection?  Is it trivial that we can always choose $C \in |d_2H|$ on $X$ such that it is smooth and moreover it is a strict complete intersection of surfaces of degrees $d_1,d_2$ (and not just a set theoretic complete intersection)?

Comment: The original question was whether the curve *can* be a plane curve. I took this to mean that there exists a (different) line bundle on the curve such that it gives an embedding to $\mathbb{P}^2$. With the genericity hypothesis, this ought to be true. (For example, if one surface is of degree $4$, then results of Ein-Lazarsfeld say that there are no (other) special line bundles on the curve.) However, proving this would require more work on existence of linear systems on special families of curves.

Comment: @New: This is called Koszul complex, I think you can find it in any textbook, e.g., it should be in Hartshorne where he discusses regular sequences. Yes, it is important that $C$ is a complete intersection as a scheme. And yes, a general complete intersection is smooth by Bertini.

Comment: @Kapil: I agree, the question about realization of a complete intersection curve as a plane curve is much more subtle.

Comment: @Sasha, I have one final question about the second part of your comment. We know that as $|d_2H|$ on general surface $X$ is base point free, by Bertini we can choose a smooth curve $C$ from it. Do you mean such a $C$ is by default a scheme theoretic intersection of $X$ and a smooth hypersurface or degree $d_2$ ( or we can always carefully choose such $C$ from the linear system such that it is both smooth and a scheme theoretic complete intersection)?

Comment: @Kapil, Can you mention the Ein-Lazarsfeld reference?

Comment: @New: Any such $C$ is complete intersection.

Comment: @New I was mistaken. The paper is by Green and Lazarsfeld. [Special Divisors on Curves on K3 surfaces](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/robert.lazarsfeld/Reprints/Green.Laz.Curves.K3.Sf.pdf)